# Route does not exist

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am new to the dupral. The site throws the error

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "entity.webform_ui.element.add_page" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()

I am confused that how i can resolve this issue. I have tried to find the solution but no luck.
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the webform_ui module enabled?

Comment: Yes it was. I figured out that the route entry in the database was missing somehow, adding the entry to that route resolve the issue.